# How do I ensure null is sent instead of 0 for empty form fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with columns that allow null values and has a default null value. On update, if the field is empty (not data inserted) my script inserts 0 instead of null. I have gone through similar questions as mine and i have tried the advice given but am still not able to fix my issue. Here's my code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    # process the form
    $student_id = $_POST["student_id"];
    $subject_id = $_POST['subject_id'];
    if (is_null($_POST["test1"])){$test1 = null;} else {$test1 = $_POST["test1"];}
    if (is_null($_POST["test2"])){$test2 = null;} else {$test2 = $_POST["test2"];}
    if (is_null($_POST["test3"])){$test3 = null;} else {$test3 = $_POST["test3"];}

    for($i=0; $i < count($student_id); $i++) {
        $studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $student_id[$i]);
        $subjectid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $subject_id);
        $test_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $test1[$i]);
        $test_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $test2[$i]);
        $test_3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $test3[$i]);

        $query = "UPDATE fullresult SET test1='{$test_1}', test2='{$test_2}', test3='{$test_3}' WHERE student_id={$studentid} AND subject_id={$subjectid}";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    }
}
?>
```

When i echo the query, this is what i see and am wondering why i still get 0 inserted

```
UPDATE fullresult SET test1=' 10', test2=' ', test3=' ' WHERE student_id=51 AND subject_id=2
```

Comment: `SET test1=" . $test_1 == null ? "null" : "'$test_1'" . " `

Comment: Are the test1.. fields integers?

Comment: @ErikTerwan yes the fields are integer

Answer (score 1):

is_null does not return true for an empty string. Try changing your if statements to something like this:

```
$test1 = trim($_POST["test1"])
if (!strlen($test1)) $test3 = null;
```

Comment: if you are only expecting numeric values you could also use the is_numeric function.

Comment: Couldn't fix it with this code either. Appreciate the input

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    # process the form
    $student_id = $_POST["student_id"];
    $subject_id = $_POST['subject_id'];

    # only retrieve FILLED IN answers
    $tests = array();
    if(isset($_POST["test1"]) && strlen($_POST["test1"])) $tests['test1'] = $_POST["test1"];
    if(isset($_POST["test2"]) && strlen($_POST["test2"])) $tests['test2'] = $_POST["test2"];
    if(isset($_POST["test3"]) && strlen($_POST["test3"])) $tests['test3'] = $_POST["test3"];

    if(!empty($tests)){ # if there were no answers, there's no point in updating the database
        for($i=0; $i < count($student_id); $i++) {
            $studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $student_id[$i]);
            $subjectid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $subject_id);

            # now let's build the "SET" part of the query
            $set = array();
            foreach($tests as $key => $value) $set[]=mysqli_real_escape_string($key)."='".mysqli_real_escape_string($value)."'";
            $set = implode(', ',$set);

            # ...and finally update
            $query = "UPDATE fullresult SET {$set} WHERE student_id={$studentid} AND subject_id={$subjectid}";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        }
    }
}
```

The point of this approach is that if you don't include a key=>value pair in your `UPDATE` query, it will be filled in with its default value.

Comment: 0 is a possible value hence the reason am not using empty(). Using isset() also gives me same result as using is_null().

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Is there a way your can try this out?

Comment: @Mena don't think so unfortunately. What problem are you experiencing now?

Comment: Still getting 0 inserted. So i came up with another way to deal with this challenge. My new plan is this, rather than have a form with multiple columns for each test am going to have one column and allow the user specify which test to update.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
ctype_digit
```

to check if there are numeric characters in it.

The function

```
mysqli::real_escape_string -- mysqli_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection
```

(Source: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Since you want to have null inside the database you should rewrite the code

```
    if (is_null($_POST["test1"])){$test1 = null;} else {$test1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["test1"]);}
```

to have the values escaped only if needed (which is in case you have a value in $_POST)

Answer (score -1):

You must set `'null'` word, not `null` value.

```
if (is_null($_POST["test1"])){$test1 = 'null';} else {$test1 = $_POST["test1"];}
if (is_null($_POST["test2"])){$test2 = 'null';} else {$test2 = $_POST["test2"];}
if (is_null($_POST["test3"])){$test3 = 'null';} else {$test3 = $_POST["test3"];}
```